# Duplicate positions from group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have the following Dataset:

```
  col  value
0    A      1
1    A    NaN
2    B    NaN
3    B    NaN
4    B    NaN
5    B      1
6    C      3
7    C    NaN
8    C    NaN
9    D      5
10   E      6
```

There is only one value set per group, the rest in Nan. What I want to do know, is fill the NaN with he value of the group. If a group has no NaNs, I just want to ignore it.
Outcome should look like this:

```
  col  value
0    A      1
1    A      1
2    B      1
3    B      1
4    B      1
5    B      1
6    C      3
7    C      3
8    C      3
9    D      5
10   E      6
```

What I've tried so far is the following:

```
df["value"] = df.groupby(col).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

However, this method is not only super slow, but doesn't give me the wished result.

Anybody an idea?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Seems not `However, this method is not only super slow, but doesn't give me the wished result.`

Comment: @jezrael Retracted my close-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of data - if there is always one non missing value you can sorting and then replace by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html), it working well if some groups has `NAN`s only:

```
df = df.sort_values(['col','value'])
df["value"] = df.groupby('col')["value"].ffill()
#if always only one non missing value per group, fail if all NaNs of some group
#df["value"] = df["value"].ffill()
print (df)
   col  value
0    A    1.0
1    A    1.0
5    B    1.0
2    B    1.0
3    B    1.0
4    B    1.0
6    C    3.0
7    C    3.0
8    C    3.0
9    D    5.0
10   E    6.0
```

Or if there is multiple values and need replace by mean, for improve performace change your solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) only `mean` passed to [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df["value"] = df["value"].fillna(df.groupby('col')["value"].transform('mean'))
print (df)
   col  value
0    A    1.0
1    A    1.0
5    B    1.0
2    B    1.0
3    B    1.0
4    B    1.0
6    C    3.0
7    C    3.0
8    C    3.0
9    D    5.0
10   E    6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ffill` which is the same as `fillna()` with `method=ffill` ([see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html))

```
df["value"] = df["value"].ffill()
```